# Javascript array length in click-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm having a hard time understanding this code. Could someone try to explain why an array can have elements and 0 length?

```
var myArray = [];
myArray["hello"] = 4;
myArray["world"] = 65;
$('#btn').on('click',function() {
    console.log(myArray.length); // Prints 0
    console.log(myArray); // Prints [hello: 4, world: 65]
    console.log(myArray.length); // Prints 0
 }
```

Comment: this is not asynchronous, and you're using a framework hidding to you 80% of the fun of javascript. So, please don't forget it in your tags (I added it for you)

Comment: you might want Object.keys(myArray).length, but you should likely use an object instead of an array.

Comment: Length only adds numerically indexed properties, you're using the `Array` in this example as a dictionary.

If you want to loop through the `Array`, you could put the `String` and `Number` into an `Object` and insert that into the `Array`.

Answer (score 4):

The `.length` property only pertains to numerically-indexed properties.

Comment: No offense, @Pointy but, although true, this isn't really the answer to the question. What he's done here is instantiate a new array object, then add properties to that object named `hello` and `world`. He's setting properties of the array *object*, not elements of the array itself.

Comment: @grinn: FWIW, array elements are so properties of the object. Every property with a numerical, positive 32bit ( or so)  property name is considered to be an element .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @acrosman the question is a duplicate; there's a fine explanation in the linked question.

Comment: @Grinn yes, as Felix Kling notes there really are no semantic differences between numerically-indexed properties and string-indexed properties; indeed, the numerically-indexed properties are really strings too! The `.length` property reflects an internal *interpretation* of the named properties, and those semantics are based on the properties whose names look like non-negative integers.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling and Pointy. I learned something new today! Here's a demonstration of what they're referring to, for those interested: http://codepen.io/grinn/pen/Lbzjc